# After unpickling system use a lot of RAM

Tags: python, pickle

I have an object (defaultdict) with structure:
{ srting : [(string, (float, float)), (string, (float, float)), ....]}

The size of it is about 12,5 MB

I am pickling with code:

```
with open(Path_to_file, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(data_dict, file)
```

Pickle file weights about 300 MB.
In proccess unpickling with code:

```
with open(Path_to_file, 'rb') as file:
    data_dict_new = pickle.load(file)
```

system is using a lot of RAM (about 3,5 GB and more). But after unpickling Python uses about 1 GB of RAM.

So I have two questions:

1. What does keep in RAM apart of my structure?
2. How can I clean it?

gc.collect() doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first question. So I have two questions: 1. What does keep in RAM apart of my structure? 2. How can I clean it?

Comment: When you pickle the object try using `pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` to select a more efficient binary [_Data Stream Format_](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) format.

Comment: Do you mean question 1: what is the overhead of pickle in RAM when reading or writing EXCLUDING the size of the "data_dict"  question 2: is there some way I can reduce the amount of RAM in use.  I cannot replicate your observations on my tests of pickle btw.  I get a large file on disk (16x RAM) and a similar amount of RAM used before the pickle "dump" and after teh pickle "load"

Comment: btw, cPickle is very much faster than pickle

Comment: Definitely not. AFTER loading pickle file (after with-block) I have only "data_dict". So, how I think memory in RAM of Python must be egual to size of "data_dict", so equals 12,5 MB. Why does it keep about 1 GB

Comment: I am using ``/usr/bin/time -f 'RSS:%M KB' python scriptname`` to see RAM in use

Comment: Might be useful, especially with regards to question 1.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53941920/2734863

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this. Indeed, if you're unpickling a large (about 300M) file, a lot of extra memory stay used. In my case, 1.6G was used by a process just to keep original generated `data_dict`, and 2.9G if I load it from file.

However, if you'll run unpickling in a subprocess, system will do a full memory clean after process `join()`. (as stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316799/1102535). So the example of unpickling without extra memory used:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def load_pickle(filename, data):
    import cPickle as pickle
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        data_pkl = pickle.load(file)
    for key, val in data_pkl.iteritems():
        data[key] = val

manager = Manager()
data_dict = manager.dict()
p = Process(target=load_pickle, args=("test.pkl", data_dict))
p.start()
p.join()
print len(data_dict)
```

This code has its drawbacks (like copying between dicts), but at least you have the idea. As for me, it uses almost the same amount of memory after unpickling as for original data before pickling.

Comment: Thank you very much for idea, but it isn't work for me. The data_dict is empty. I use Python 3. The reason maybe here.

Comment: The function "load_pickle" isn't called.

Comment: Yes, this code was tested with Python 2.7. I just made a test with Python 3 also, and cannot reproduce memory issue at all. The amount of used RAM seems to be the same after unpickling as it was before, even without subprocess trick. If you can provide a full example of how you're testing, it would be very helpful. Btw, I measured process memory usage with ``top`` command, not ``time``.

Comment: I use the Task Manager before starts code and after. At first RAM doesn't use and after the start 1 GB of memory is used. The volume of my structure is defined by a function `sys.getsizeof()`.