# Why loading a pickle file into memory will take much more space?

Tags: python, memory, pickle

I have a folder contains 7603 files saved by `pickle.dump`. The average file size is `6.5MB`, so the total disk space the files take is about `48GB`.

Each file is obtained by pickling a list object, the list has a structure of

```
[A * 50] 
 A = [str, int, [92 floats], B * 3] 
                             B = [C * about 6] 
                                  C = [str, int, [92 floats]]
```

The memory of the computer I'm using is `128GB`.

However, I cannot load all the files in the folder into memory by this script:

```
import pickle
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
from os.path import join
from os import listdir
import os

def one_loader(the_arg):
    with open(the_arg, 'rb') as source:
        temp_fp = pickle.load(source)
    the_hash = the_arg.split('/')[-1]
    os.system('top -bn 1 | grep buff >> memory_log')
    return (the_hash, temp_fp)

def process_parallel(the_func, the_args):
    pool = mp.Pool(25)
    result = dict(pool.map(the_func, the_args))
    pool.close()
    return result

node_list = sys.argv[-1]
db_path =  db_path
the_hashes = listdir(db_path)
the_files = [join(db_path, item) for item in the_hashes]
fp_dict = {}
fp_dict = process_parallel(one_loader, the_files)
```

I have plotted the memory usage as you can see from the script, the memory usage is

[image]

I have several confusions about this plot:

1. 4000 files take `25GB` disk space, but why they take more than `100GB` memory?
2. After the sudden drop of the memory usage, I received no error, and I can see the script was still running by using `top` command. But I have completely no idea of what the system was doing, and where are the rest of the memories.

Comment: you're not just loading file into memory, you also unpickle it to objects which takes more space.

Comment: This is **very** specific to the format of the file (both on-disk and in-memory formats); that format should be included in the question itself to give the question any hope of not being too broad/general to be permissible. (I've edited to do so here). That said, to speak more generally,  deserialization will often involve decompression, and then will *almost always* involve breaking a single stream into a series of separate objects. Objects have overhead in memory -- they need garbage-collection metadata; they may need to have indexes created for fast access; etc.

Comment: The details of how much overhead and for what depends on the details of what the objects are; there does not exist any generic answer, or any universal ratio of storage requirements.

Comment: @Charles Duffy I have added details about the object being pickled.

Comment: If you want to cut down the size, maybe using `numpy` and storing your floating point data in `float` (with a loss of precision, but that can be acceptable) will reduce the size it takes on disk AND in memory

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: BTW, if your `A`, `B` and `C` are... well, *objects*, you can also reduce memory overhead by using `__slots__` rather than relying on the default dictionary-based implementation. Doesn't apply if the illustration reflects reality and they're lists, of course; in that case, array types (as provided by numpy, or the built-in array module) are indeed the Right Thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just because serialized data takes less space than the space in memory needed to manage the object when running.

Example with a string:

```
import pickle

with open("foo","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump("toto",f)
```

`foo` is 14 bytes on the disk (including pickle header or whatever) but in memory it's much bigger:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof('toto')
53
```

for a dictionary it's even worse, because of the hash tables (and other stuff):

```
import pickle,os,sys

d = {"foo":"bar"}
with open("foo","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(d,f)
print(os.path.getsize("foo"))
print(sys.getsizeof(d))
```

result:

```
27
288
```

so a 1 to 10 ratio.